# Cosa significa "esaudire" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Le era venuta una gran placidezza: l'uscio chiuso e il tranquillo compagno le davano un agio, un calore che non aveva mai provati, né sola né in compagnia, e neppure con suo padre. Non si ricordava di essere la Gentileschi, pittrice e figlia di pittore. Riscuoteva antichi crediti di benevolenza familiare, di familiare rispetto. Aveva -- e la parola continuava a **esaudire** il suo pensiero -- aveva un marito.

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esaudire/) "esaudire" significa "dare ascolto e concedere ciò che viene richiesto". Tuttavia, non capisco cosa significa che la parola che era in quel momento nella mente di Artemisia esaudiva il suo pensiero. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Secondo me, senza sapere il contesto, *esaudire* si riferisce ad *aveva*: sembra quasi che *l'avere...* sia ciò che la dà soddisfazione, più del *...marito*.

Comment: @N74: Io ho pensato che fosse la parola che veniva giusto dopo "aveva", cioè la parola "marito", che è quella che occupa la mente della pittrice in quel momento. Artemisia si era sposata, ma era partita per Firenze giusto dopo il matrimonio, in modo che non aveva potuto convivere con suo marito. Durante il viaggio di ritorno a Roma pensa solo a suo marito che la sta aspettando. Questa frase si riferisce al giorno in cui Artemisia ritrova suo marito: il libro spiega che la pittrice sente una placidezza, un agio, un calore che non aveva mai provati prima.

Comment: @N74: Ma, come spiegato anche da Erik, forse hai ragione e "la parola" è "aveva", nel senso che il fatto che è veramente importante per Artemisia in quel momento è "avere" un marito per davvero. Per questa ragione, ho aggiornato la domanda.

Comment: Credo vi sia un sottile rimando alla placidezza in incipit; il pensiero - per es. quando si domanda, magari non trovando risposte - può dare anche inquietitudine, e talvolta una idea, magari suscitata dal sentire (mentalmente) una parola, qui 'avere',  la placa, come il calmarsi del questuante quando la sua richiesta è esaudita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il [verbo esaudire](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/esaudire) significa anche

> soddisfare, accontentare qcn.

Artemisia sta pensando al marito, e di fatto **ha** un marito. Quasi sembra che non fosse sposata ma il fatto di averlo in realtà *soddisfa* i suoi pensieri verso il marito con cui non ha vissuto. La parola fa coincidere realtà e pensiero.
Senza contesto l'impressione è che la frase sia più diretta alla condizione dell'essere sposata piuttosto che alla persona del marito. Sarebbe plausibile visto che, nella situazione in cui era la Gentileschi, l'essere sposata o no faceva differenza.

Comment: Quindi, in questo contesto, "esaudire" significherebbe "soddisfare"? Cioè, la parola che Artemisia ha in mente soddisfa il suo pensiero (veramente non importa tanto se tale parola è "aveva" oppure "marito").

Comment: soddisfare: essere in accordo con  (Treccani)

Comment: @Charo: vedila come nell'espressione *esaudire ogni suo desiderio* -> *soddisfare ogni suo desiderio*.

Comment: Che si riferisca al marito vero e proprio perché le manca come persona, o che si riferisca alla condizione di donna sposata che porta rispettabilità, cambia un poco il senso della frase ma non della parola che usano. Però potrebbe essere più facile per te capire la parola se il senso è chiaro.

Comment: Per esempio: se l'essere sposata, il marito, come concetto sono un pensiero nella sua testa, l'**avere** il marito lo fa diventare una cosa reale vera e palpabile. Non ha la persona davanti a sé, non ha vissuto "da moglie" ma **ha** un marito, per davvero

Comment: @N74:  Capisco che "esaudire un desiderio" si possa esprimere anche come "soddisfare un desiderio" perché, secondo il Treccani, significa "dare ascolto e concedere" questo desiderio. Ma non è detto che "esaudire" sia sempre lo stesso di "soddisfare". O sì lo è?

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Sono d'accordo, penso che il senso della frase sia quello che tu hai detto.

Comment: Con la definizione di quest'altro dizionario, ho capito il significato. Grazie mille! E grazie anche a @N74 che mi ha fatto vedere questo.

Answer (score 1):

> Aveva -- e la parola continuava a esaudire il suo pensiero -- aveva un marito.

Secondo quel che ho inteso io, "la parola" si riferisce ad "Aveva"; essendo *esaudire* [sinonimo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esaudire_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/) di *soddisfare* ed avendo *soddisfare* anche il [significato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soddisfare/) di:

> **essere in accordo con, rispondere a**, in espressioni come *s. a una premessa, a un principio, s. a una condizione*,

il verbo *avere* è proprio quello che esprime nella maniera più completa in assoluto quello che era il pensiero della pittrice: l'*essere in possesso* di un marito (quasi equiparato ad un bene), l'essersi finalmente ricongiunta a lui.